# Divide Total Rows by Total of all rows - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a table which stores tips and inside this table is a row of odds.

I need to workout the average odds of all tips

e.g Average Odds = Sum of all odds / Number of Tips

However I cannot workout how to do this in my Controller on Laravel...

I can get total rows with $totaltips = Tip::count();

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has methods for counting and summing:  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries.

```
$tips = Tip::count();
$odds = Tip::sum('your_odds_column');
$average = false;
// Don't divide by zero
if ( $tips > 0 ) {
    $average = $odds / $tips;
}
```